# Why does my UITableView only show the list of available MGLOfflinePacks after I leave the current view controller and return to it?

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm using Mapbox-iOS-SDK 3.3.7 with Swift 3 to develop a feature that would let users download maps for offline use. The initial view will have a UITableView that will provide a list of all previously downloaded MGLOfflinePacks. I did my best to port to Swift 3 the [Objective-C example that Mapbox provides](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/ios-v3.3.7/platform/ios/app/MBXOfflinePacksTableViewController.m) for managing offline packs.

Unfortunately, I'm running into a problem where the offline packs do not appear when the table is initially displayed. However, if I push another controller onto the NavigationController or otherwise leave and return to the UITableView, the list of offline packs appears as expected.

I believe that my Notification observers and KVO are properly set up according to [the documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.3.7/Classes/MGLOfflineStorage.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLOfflineStorage(py)packs) but no matter what I try, `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` always returns 0 until I leave the controller and return, presumably because MGLOfflineStorage.shared().packs returns nil when the code gets triggered to check it.

Here are the relevant parts of the code I'm using that I ported from the aforementioned Obj-C example:

```
import Mapbox

class OfflineMapTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // observers for offline pack loading
        MGLOfflineStorage.shared().addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "paths", options: .initial, context: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(offlinePackProgressDidChange), name: NSNotification.Name.MGLOfflinePackProgressChanged, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        MGLOfflineStorage.shared().removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "paths")
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        guard let change = change else { return }

        if keyPath == "paths" {
            if let changeKind = change[NSKeyValueChangeKey.kindKey] as? UInt,
                let kind = NSKeyValueChange(rawValue: changeKind) {

                var indexPaths: [IndexPath] = []

                if let indexes = change[NSKeyValueChangeKey.indexesKey] as? NSIndexSet {
                    if indexes.count > 0 {
                        indexes.enumerate({ (index, stop) in
                            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))
                        })
                    }
                }

                switch kind {
                case NSKeyValueChange.insertion:
                    tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
                    break

                case NSKeyValueChange.removal:
                    tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
                    break

                case NSKeyValueChange.replacement:
                    tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
                    break

                default:
                    tableView.reloadData()

                    if let packs = MGLOfflineStorage.shared().packs {
                        for pack in packs {
                            if pack.state == .unknown {
                                pack.requestProgress()
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    break
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        }
    }

    func offlinePackProgressDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let pack = notification.object as? MGLOfflinePack else { return }

        guard let index = MGLOfflineStorage.shared().packs?.index(of: pack) else { return }

        let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            updateTableViewCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath, forPack: pack)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let packs = MGLOfflineStorage.shared().packs {
            return packs.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "idCell", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...

        if let pack = MGLOfflineStorage.shared().packs?[indexPath.row] {
            updateTableViewCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath, forPack: pack)
        }

        return cell
    }

    func updateTableViewCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath, forPack pack: MGLOfflinePack) {

        if let userInfo = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: pack.context) as? [String: String] {
            if let name = userInfo["name"] {
                cell.textLabel?.text = name
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Anyone know why the list of offline packs only appears when I leave then return to the view controller?

Comment: Is the 'default' switch case statement ever called? tableView.reloadData() should be called as soon as `MGLOfflineStorage.shared().packs` is updated.

Comment: @RemyCilia Yes, the "default" switch is called but it's strange because `MGOfflineStorage.shared().packs` returns nil when it should actually be returning the available packs. Only when I return to this controller does that property return the available packs.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `forKeyPath: "paths"` to `forKeyPath: "packs"`.

The name of the `MGLOfflineStorage` property is `packs`.